# Как сделать не стандартные списки?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать не стандартные элементы списка `ListView`
Например я хочу добавить `картинку` и `small text` на каждый элемент списка, как можно это сделать?
Сейчас я устанавливаю список с помощью функции:

```
ListView listView;
```

дальше в oncreate

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

ChatsVoider.UpdateChats(context); --готовит массив

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ChatsVoider.NameChats);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

устанавливает массив в список...

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста тот код, который есть сейчас. И описание цели: что сделать нужно, для чего нужен этот список?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще один способ реализовать список это унаследоваться от одного из классов адаптера и переопределить метод `getView()`. Например можно унаследоваться от BaseAdapter реализовать абстрактные методы `getItemId(int position)`, `getItem(int position)` и `getCount()`, а так же переопределить метод `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`. После чего в данный адаптер можно будет передавать коллекцию из собственных элементов и отображать их как захочется.

В методе `getItemId(int position)` необходимо вернуть идентификатор элемента по переданной позиции. Если у элемента нет такого идентификатора, то можно возвращать позицию, которую передали в функцию как параметр.

В методе `getItem(int position)` надо вернуть элемент из коллекции по переданной позиции.

В методе `getCount()` надо вернуть общее количество элементов в коллекции.

В методе `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` необходимо реализовать логику отображения элемента списка. Первым делом необходимо создать `view` которое будет являться элементом списка, после чего заполнить все необходимые поля в этом `view` и вернуть его из функции.

Так же при работе с `ListView` не стоит забывать использовать паттерн [ViewHolder](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder), что позволит добиться более плавного прокручивания списка за счет уменьшения вызовов `findViewById()` для поиска полей необходимых для заполнения.

После реализации такого адаптера, создавать и устанавливать его можно тем же способом что и обычные адаптеры.

Ниже представлен код адаптера.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final List<MyCustomObject> mObjects;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyCustomObject> products) {
        mObjects = products;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mObjects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MyViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (view == null) {
            //Если элемент списка еще не был создан, то создаем его 
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            //Создаем экземпляр ViewHolder'a, он будет хранить поля, которые будем заполнять
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
            viewHolder.title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
            // Устанавливаем для view экземпляр ViewHolder'a
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            //если элемент уже был создан, то получаем экземпляр ViewHolder'a
            viewHolder = (MyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyCustomObject item = (MyCustomObject)getItem(position);

        // заполняем поля
        viewHolder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        viewHolder.description.setText(item.getDescription());

        return view;
    }

    private static class MyViewHolder{

        public TextView title;
        public TextView description;
    }
}
```

Класс, который содержит данные для отображения:

```
public class MyCustomObject {

    private String title;
    private String description;

    private void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    private void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    private String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    private String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

}
```

Способ использования в `Activity`:

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.my_list);
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, objects);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Интересный способ, тоже опробую его!

Answer (score 1):

Создайте объект, допустим

```
class CustomItem {
    int image;
    String text;
}
```

И используйте список `ArrayList<CustomImage> list`

Comment: Я думаю может это не совсем то, я делаю установку текущего списка вот так, `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ChatsVoider.NameChats);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);` как это улучшить?

Comment: как я понял вам необходимо использовать  Map: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/107-urok-48-ispolzuem-simpleadapter.html

Comment: ценная догадка про Map.

Comment: О, спасибо, читаю, то что надо

Comment: Да, все работает! код под себя подделал, правда копировать немного пришлось:) но вот после манипуляций я имею списки которым я могу установить разный текст картинку, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Кортеж из двух элементов, immutable. Если нужно хранить примитивы, используйте соответствующие обертки (`int` > `Integer` и т.п)

```
public class Tuple<X, Y> { 
  public final X x; 
  public final Y y; 
  public Tuple(X x, Y y) { 
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
  } 
} 


List<Tuple<Image, String>> list = new LinkedList<Tuple<Image, String>>();
Image img;
String str;
list.add(new Tuple(img, str));
```

Comment: Ты предлагаешь разместить обьекты по x y?)

Comment: @ДенисКотляров: это код универсального кортежа для элементов двух произвольных классов, экземпляры которого можно хранить в списке (но нежелательно в ассоциативном массиве). А в чем вопрос-то?